# Switching between text output on button press on android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to have one TextView switch from one sentence to another alongside my ImageSwitcher. Here is a sample code for my activity

```
    private Integer images[]={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4....};
private int currImage=0;
private Integer text[]={R.string.text0,R.string.text1,R.string.text2,R.string.text3,R.string.text4....};

@Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeImageSwitcher();
    setInitialImage();
    setImageRotateListener();

    setInitialText();

}


private void initializeImageSwitcher() {
    final ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageswitcher);
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            return imageView;
        }
    });

    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_in));
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_out));
}

private void setImageRotateListener() {
    final ImageButton rightarrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    rightarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            currImage++;
            if (currImage == 29) {
                currImage = 0;
            }
            setCurrentImage();
            setCurrentText();
        }
    });
}


private void setInitialImage() {
    setCurrentImage();
}

private void setInitialText(){
    setCurrentText();
}

private void setCurrentImage() {
    final ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageswitcher);
    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[currImage]);
}

private void setCurrentText() {
    final TextView textSwitcher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textSwitcher.setText(Integer.toString(text[currImage]));
}
```

The it compiles and run just fine. Issue lies in the text output. Instead of the sentences defined in the string, the TextView displays a series of numbers.

For example:

```
  <string name="text1">Sentence one</string>
<string name="text2">Sentence two</string>
<string name="text3">Sentence three</string>
<string name="text4">Sentence four</string>
```

The output for "text1" would be 8513856, "text2" would be 841363, "text3" would be 18413587, and so on.

If anyone one has an idea of how to solve this issue, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying the resource id's of the strings, not the strings themselves.
Change to:

```
private void setCurrentText() {
final TextView textSwitcher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textSwitcher.setText(getResources().getString(text[currImage]));
}
```

Comment: @hamdummy you could also use ContextCompat.getString(text[currImage]) as well